# Excel VBA - Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: vba

I'm getting Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'ID_Unique = ID_Unique FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\luiveg\Desktop\Databasetest\DB Macro Test.xlsm].[rawdata$].

Here is the code I am using:

```
Sub Upload_Excel_to_AccessUPDATE()

Dim wbpath As String

wbpath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path


Dim con As Object  '' ADODB.Connection
Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")  '' New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data source=\\an\HRS SD Performance Data\Capacity DB.accdb;"
con.Execute _
         "UPDATE AssigenedVol_tbl " & _
            "SET Volume = Volume " & _
            "WHERE ID_Unique = ID_Unique " & _
            "FROM [Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=2;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\leg\Desktop\DB Macro Test.xlsm].[rawdata$]"
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

So let's say that ID_Unique is the primary key in Table. We already have records in the table (Process_Identifier, Login, Volume, effDate, ID_Unique ), we want to update Volume based on ID_Unique if it already exists, if the ID_Unique does not exists we want to add Process_Identifier, Login, Volume, effDate, ID_Unique data from excel to the data base.

Example of excel data:

```
Process_Identifier  Login   Volume  effDate     ID_Unique
O1FA73              rohen   0       5/31/2019   E2-anriz-I1FA05-05/30/2019
O1FA76              jiz     0       5/31/2019   cmposc-I1FA05-05/30/2019
I1FA05              jiz     10      5/31/2019   cmposc-O1FA73-05/30/2019
O1FA73              cmpsc   10      5/31/2019   jriz-I1FA05-05/30/2019
I1FA05              cmpsc   0       5/31/2019   jriz-O1FA76-05/30/2019
I1FA05              aniz    20      5/31/2019   rodrhen-O1FA73-05/30/2019
I1FA05              luieg   90      5/31/2019   luiveg-I1FA05-05/30/2019
```

The issue is that I am very new to VBA/macros/coding in general and have no idea how to execute this, so I am looking for any help, assitance, or pointer fingers in the right direction that someone could provide.

Thanks in advance for any and all insight!

Comment: Read: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?478008-RESOLVED-Syntax-error-(-missing-operator-)-in-query-expression post #3 and #8 in it. It can dispatch you to new options. It seems some apostrophes missing in your query string. It depends on  data type of your target.

Comment: Hi. I dont understand what u are doing. First u open a conection to a access database, but in the query u are  looking for a sheet in a excel file. U should look for a table that exists in the access database, no?

Comment: Thanks @VitezslavSimon I am trying it. And Luis Curado I am trying to export data from excel to a database(table) in Access, since a lot of users are using it I want to make it easy with a button (VBA code) that insert or update the above information.

Comment: this post resolved my issue https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/general-excel-discussion-other-questions/1099590-updating-adding-record-access-excel-vba.html#post5286609